# Is possible to decrypt encrypted emails sent by a database to users in LN?

Tags: encryption, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I have been asked to work on disabling encryption for email via Lotus Notes. Some LN databases on my organisation send emails to people with some kind of action required to be performed. Not all users in my company have Notes/Domino as their email/calendaring platform, and encrypted email is unreadable for those whom do not have the Notes client installed. One of them is an important user and uses Outlook and Apple Mail, but this what that person see instead of the entire message:
Dear User An e-mail was sent to you from Lotus Domino containing special objects accessible only via the Lotus Notes Client. The remediated message is below, but may be missing some content.

I did a quick research and noted that at the moment the user sent the document from the database, using a basic form with Sendto, Cc, Bcc , Subject and Body fields, the possible field that would be used by encryption ($EncryptionStatus) shows 0, and this makes me think that the encryption is might not on the application side, but on the server side.

Is there a way to decrypt on server side or LN can not be changed? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to encrypt mail: you can add fields to encrypt mails automatically on send. But you can also setup the recipient to encrypt all incoming mail without the application / sender doing so. Please check the person document of the recipient if it is set to encrypt all mails to him. IF a mail is encrypted you can only decrypt it with the notes id of the sender or of one of the recipients. If not one of them is a server, then there is no easy way to automatically decrpyt the messages as you cannot run agents on a server with another Id as the servers‘ id (run on behalf will not work here, as it does not have access to the private key of the user). Then you could give the user an Hcl Nomad client on his ios device to read the encrypted mails...

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response Torsten, but on this database there is no encryption field, and it seems the server is adding the field $EncryptionStatus, which is 0 when sent. I know that in LN email we can configure it, since there is another option to encrypt incoming emails. But this is Outlook/Apple Mail, and I do not know if that is the case, if in Outlook/Apple Mail configuration they have that set on their side. So, my question is there a way to remove from Domino side encryption of emails when sending via database ?

Comment: If this user has a mail file on the Domino server and is using Outlook/Apple Mail to access the messages from the Domino server, then the Domino router will be enforcing the encryption setting in the user's Person document at the time that the message is sent.